# How to call all list items in a list based on item count

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to code a simple bruteforcer in Python, mainly to put my Python knowledge to the test. I have the number of items in a list, but I want to make "brutedata" have that same number of items. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
while count < contentscount - 1:
    count = count + 1
    brutedata = { postdata[0] : "admin", postdata[1] : contents[count] }
    brute = requests.post(target, data=brutedata)
    bruteresponse = brute.text
```

For example, if there are 3 POST parameters specified, brutedata will be:

```
brutedata = { postdata[0] : "value", postdata[1] : "value", postdata[2] : "value" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a dictionary with a dict comprehension:

```
brutedata = {'postdata[{}]'.format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(itemlist)}
```

This produces a dictionary with N keys, keys named `postdata[0]`, `postdata[1]`, ..., `postdata[N]` with values in the same order as the input `itemlist` elements.

This syntax requires Python 2.7 or newer; for older versions, you can use the `dict()` constructor with a generator expression producing (key, value) pairs:

```
brutedata = dict(('postdata[{0}]'.format(i), v) for i, v in enumerate(itemlist))
```

Demo:

```
>>> itemlist = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> {'postdata[{}]'.format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(itemlist)}
{'postdata[1]': 'bar', 'postdata[2]': 'baz', 'postdata[0]': 'foo'}
>>> dict(('postdata[{0}]'.format(i), v) for i, v in enumerate(itemlist))
{'postdata[1]': 'bar', 'postdata[2]': 'baz', 'postdata[0]': 'foo'}
```

Take into account dictionaries have no set order; the fact that `postdata[0]` is listed after the other two keys in the sample output is simply due to the implementation details of the underlying hash table used for `dict`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for. How would I go about assigning seperate values to each of those list-items, though? Seeing as I'm using the requests library, I need to create POST-data for it to send to the server. Example

    brutedata = { "username" : postdata[0], "password" : postdata[1] }

Comment: @user2879373: generally speaking, you'd already have a mapping of fieldname to value in that case. How did you produce `postdata` in the  first place?

Comment: postdata = raw_input("Post data> ")
postdata = postdata.split('&')
postdata = [p.split('=', 1)[0] for p in postdata]



INPUT>>>username=asd&password=asd 
OUTPUT>>>(postdata[0] = username, postdata[1] = password)

Comment: @user2879373: Use the [`urlparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to parse a query string into key, value pairs instead.

Comment: @user2879373: That way you retain the keys, and can replace values as needed.